# How to encode/decode XML in VBA and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, vba

I currently have a program that trasfer data from VBA (Access) to C# (via ASP.NET POST).  How do I encode/decode on each end?

Here is my XML read in C#:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
string xmlData = "";
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd();
XmlElement rootXML;
xml.LoadXml(xmlData);
rootXML = xml.DocumentElement;
```

Here is my XML write in C#:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
Response.Write(XML_in_String);
Response.End();
```

Here is my XML write in VBA

```
connection.Open "POST", server & "www.webpage.com/" & postData, False
connection.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/xml"
connection.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
connection.send "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?><data>" & outXMLstr & "</data>"
```

Here is my XML read in VBA

```
Dim inXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Set inXML = New DOMDocument
inXML.loadXML (connection.responseText)
```

Specifically, I got an error in C# when trying to loadXML(xmlData) because it can't parse the ampersand (&).

Comment: it you want to encode ampersand to &amp; the use Server.HtmlEncode & Server.HtmlDecode

Comment: Where is the ampersand it's having problems with - in your XML ?  Can you show that part of the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `xmlData`, have you tried as @HatSoft says, to use `Server.HtmlEncode`/`Server.HtmlDecode`? That way you could get rid of htmlentities that doesn't work in XML.

Or you could wrap your data into a CDATA-field

[Decode CDATA section in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236785/decode-cdata-section-in-c-sharp)

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp