# Retrieving Value of an XElement where value is <![CDATA[12345]]>

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cdata

If i have the following xml element:

```
 <TEST><![CDATA[12345]]></TEST>
```

I'm trying to extract the value of a `<TEST>` xml element using below code:

```
  XElement elem = documet.XPathSelectElement(xpath_to_TEST); //xpath_to_TEST is the actual xpath to that element
  var value = elem.value //value of <TEST>
```

The problem with code above is that `value` variable contains `12345` where i want to get whole value of `<TEST>` as string including CDATA markups like `<![CDATA[12345]]>`.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I believe if you need CDATA element you should just dig into child elements instead of asking for value. Side note: CDATA is just a way to represent value of the node and generally should not really matter. Sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236785/decode-cdata-section-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I realize that however the logic is to be able to decompse a XML element by breaking down each Element and its exact value so that in later date user can reconstruct a response through a different process. I just need to be able to get EXACT value of a given xml element so if it has markup then i need to keep it, in this case CDATA is importat to keep otherwise it becomes data that i've lost from original input.

Comment: As I've linked I believe you are looking for something like `DescendantNodes().OfType<XCData>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to treat the element content as [`XCData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) node, for example :

```
XElement elem = documet.XPathSelectElement(xpath_to_TEST);
XCData xcdata = (XCData)elem.FirstNode;
Console.WriteLine(xcdata.ToString());
//above prints :
//<![CDATA[12345]]>
```

related question : [How to do edit text content keeping it in a CDATA block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532044/how-to-do-edit-text-content-keeping-it-in-a-cdata-block)